# Does DOM support pass by reference for nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Right now if you want to reuse a certain dom element, you clone it and then append it. If you just append it then it's removed from its previous position, i.e. only one of it can exist. Therefore, you clone it first. Which is great in scnearios where that's needed behavior but not in all situations, for example. If it has an iframe, cloning it would cause to refetch the iframe each time.

But if you could refer, pass by reference, to existing DOM node then you'd only have one copy of a dom and wont need to clone.

Comment: Each iframe has to maintain its own browsing context. You can't have multiple iframes in sync.

Comment: Exactly, I don't want multiple iFrames, I want a reference to same iframe not clone it